# Spring JDBC BeanPropertyRowMapper yes no ('Y','N') to boolean bean properties

Tags: database, oracle, spring, boolean, spring-jdbc

I have a class with some string, int and boolean fields. I have the getters and setters declared for them.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private int id;
    private String description;
    private boolean active;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }


}
```

I am BeanPropertyRowMapper to get all the objects from and Oracle DB.

```
@Override
public List<Destination> getAll() {
     List<SomeClass> objs = jdbcTemplate.query(
                myQuery, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<SomeClass>(SomeClass.class));
     return objs;
}
```

If the debug is turned on I see:

```
[3/14/13 10:02:09:202 EDT] 00000018 SystemOut     O DEBUG BeanPropertyRowMapper - Mapping column 'ID' to property 'id' of type int
[3/14/13 10:02:09:202 EDT] 00000018 SystemOut     O DEBUG BeanPropertyRowMapper - Mapping column 'DESCRIPTION' to property 'description' of type class java.lang.String
```

And then it fails trying to map active. Active is defined as 1 byte CHAR in the DB with values as 'Y' or 'N'. What is the best way to use BeanPropertyRowMapper and successfully convert values such as 'Y', and 'N' to boolean?

Comment: You're better off writing your own custom RowMapper than trying to find out why Spring can't convert boolean Y to boolean true. Or change your database mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your info. How do I change database mapping to solve this since oracle does not have a boolean type? I think there is some value in using beanpropertyrowmapper, because it helps save lot of boilerplate code especially if you have a lot of domain objects. It helps to spend more time and focus on business logic than dataaccess.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that Oracle doesn't have boolean type. I've been reading up on `BeanPropertyRowMapper` and apparently this was supposed to be (and is?) fixed in [Spring 2.5.2](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4355). You might have to play with the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` methods though.

Comment: Hi @Sotirios, thanks for pointing in the right direction. See my solution below. Feedback welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I figured out how to do this. I extended BeanPropertyRowMapper and handler boolean types through some custom code before handing off the control to beanpropertyrowmapper for rest of the data types.

Note: It works for me because I use oracle and all of the 'boolean' type columns are strings with 'y','yes','n' & 'no' type values.

Those who use numerical 1,0 or other formats could potentially improve it further by making it generic through an object yes map and getting objects from resultset and looking them up in this map. Hope this helps someone else in a situation like mine.

```
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;

/**
 * Extends BeanPropertyRowMapper to allow for boolean fields
 * mapped to 'Y,'N' type column to get set correctly. Using stock BeanPropertyRowMapper
 * would throw a SQLException.
 * 
 */
public class ExtendedBeanPropertyRowMapper<T> extends BeanPropertyRowMapper<T> {

    //Contains valid true values
    public static final Set<String> TRUE_SET = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("y", "yes", "true"));

    public ExtendedBeanPropertyRowMapper(Class<T> class1) {
        super(class1);
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Override <code>getColumnValue</code> to add ability to map 'Y','N' type columns to
     * boolean properties.
     * 
     * @param rs is the ResultSet holding the data
     * @param index is the column index
     * @param pd the bean property that each result object is expected to match
     * (or <code>null</code> if none specified)
     * @return the Object value
     * @throws SQLException in case of extraction failure
     * @see org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper#getColumnValue(java.sql.ResultSet, int, PropertyDescriptor) 
     */
    protected Object getColumnValue(ResultSet rs, int index,
            PropertyDescriptor pd) throws SQLException {
        Class<?> requiredType = pd.getPropertyType();
        if (boolean.class.equals(requiredType) || Boolean.class.equals(requiredType)) {
            String stringValue = rs.getString(index);
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(stringValue) && TRUE_SET.contains(stringValue.toLowerCase())){
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }       
        return super.getColumnValue(rs, index, pd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`BeanPropertyRowMapper` will convert values into a `Boolean` object with `0=false` and `1=true`. Just tried this and it works.

[This blog post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-choosing-an-efficient-design-for-boolean-column-values/) has more information, as well as code examples in Java and C with OCCI.

Comment: Its better to add information into the answer and keeping the link for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but you can do something like

```
public void setIsActive(String active) {
    this.active = "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(active);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Harikumar, `BeanPropertyRowMapper` does in fact convert 0 and 1 to boolean values. I couldn't find any documentation to support this, but this is in fact the current case.

So, a solution that doesn't require you to extend `BeanPropertyRowMapper` would be to decode your column into these values:

```
@Override
public List<Destination> getAll() {
     List<SomeClass> objs = jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, " +
                " DECODE(ACTIVE, 'Y', 1,'N', 0) as ACTIVE " +
                " FROM YOUR_TABLE",
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<SomeClass>(SomeClass.class));
     return objs;
}
```