# BeanPropertyRowMapper not converting mysql tinyint 1 to boolean true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
public class Foo {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean isBar;

    public long getId() {
        return id;   
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;   
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean isBar() {
        return isBar;
    }
    public void setBar(boolean isBar) {
        this.isBar = isBar;
    }
}

@Component
public class FooDAO {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private FooDAO(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
   
    public List<Foo> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query( "SELECT * FROM foo", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Foo.class);
    }
}
```

When I setup a custom `FooRowMapper` and manually call `setBar(rs.getBoolean("is_bar"))` `Foo.isBar` is properly getting set to true when db value is 1, but not when using the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` instead of a custom row mapper.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500002/6496965), `BeanPropertyRowMapper` should properly convert 1 to true, so why isn't it in my case?

p.s. I already figured out why but thought I'd post it in case it's helpful to anybody. I'm sure it won't take long for someone else to figure it out and post the answer.

Comment: Can you debug the issue? Create a breakpoint in `setBar`, backtrack to the place where the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` converts and sets the value.

Comment: @f1sh yeah that or add a print statement inside `setBar` narrows it down since `setBar` isn't executing.

Comment: `is_bar` doesn't match `setBar`. Your setter should be `setIsBar` and the getter should be `isIsBar` (if you use it for mapping back).

Answer (score 0):

I knew [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html):

> Column values are mapped based on matching the column name as obtained from result set meta-data to public setters for the corresponding properties. The names are matched either directly or by transforming a name separating the parts with underscores to the same name using "camel" case.

But got thrown off because my `Foo.isBar` property had the correct camel case equivalent of my db field name (`is_bar`), however, my public setter name was incorrect as `setBar`; the setter should be `setIsBar`.

After googling I was also thrown off by others wanting to use `BeanPropertyRowMapper` to convert database values of Y/N to boolean values.

And I also assumed `BeanPropertyRowMapper` was actually setting the value to `false` even though it wasn't and the `false` value simply remained as the default boolean primitive value.

Another solution if for whatever reason `setBar` instead `setIsBar` was actually desired would be to use an field alias in the sql select statement like it says in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html):

> To facilitate mapping between columns and fields that don't have matching names, try using column aliases in the SQL statement like "select fname as first_name from customer".